# Does Windows Azure support the Application Warm-Up module or something similar?

Tags: asp.net, iis, azure

We have a Web Role that we are hosting in Windows Azure that uses an old ASMX based Web Reference to contact an external system.  The Web Reference proxy code is big enough that instantiating it the first time has a significant cost.

We'd like to be able to have this run when the Web Role starts instead of on the first request.

I know IIS 7.5 has an [Application Warm-Up](http://www.iis.net/expand/ApplicationWarmUp) module that would allow us to achieve this, but I'm having trouble figuring out if something similar exists with hosting on Windows Azure.

Thanks,
Corey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Application_Start handler in Global.asax gets executed when the Web Role is deployed (for ASP.NET) and not on the first request, so that will work for us.

Answer (score 5):

I like the solution from Steve Marx.

Add this lines to ***ServiceDefinition.csdef:***

```
<Startup>
  <Task commandLine="startup\disableTimeout.cmd" executionContext="elevated" />
</Startup>
```

And add ***disableTimeout.cmd*** in a folder called ***startup***, with the following line of code:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00
```

Original solution from here: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/controlling-application-pool-idle-timeouts-in-windows-azure

When running in the emulator please read this: http://blog.smarx.com/posts/skipping-windows-azure-startup-tasks-when-running-in-the-emulator

Comment: This is great, but note that it prevents app pool from being shut down so frequently rather than automatically restarting it when it is shut down. You'll still have the app recycled after 29 hours (by default) ... won't that then take a while to start up?

Comment: Also worth taking note that the .cmd file really needs to be in ASCII encoding and not UTF-8 like visual studio creates by default, else you'll hit problems. See 'Batch files and Visual Studio' in http://blog.smarx.com/posts/windows-azure-startup-tasks-tips-tricks-and-gotchas

Answer (score 0):

An update on this, the article below shows how to configure a Windows Azure `WebRole`:

http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/iis-8-0-application-initialization-module-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/

You can install the module in a startup batch script using:

```
PKGMGR.EXE /iu:IIS-ApplicationInit
```

Then in the WebRole (I've adapted this to work with a WebRole hosting multiple websites):

```
public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        using (var serverManager = new ServerManager())
        {
            // The foreach ensures we enable initialization for all websites hosted on this WebRole.
            foreach (var application in serverManager.Sites.SelectMany(x => x.Applications))
            {
                application["preloadEnabled"] = true;
            }

            foreach (var applicationPool in serverManager.ApplicationPools)
            {
                applicationPool["startMode"] = "AlwaysRunning";
            }

            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }

        base.Run();
    }

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // For information on handling configuration changes
        // see the MSDN topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166357.

        return base.OnStart();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374886/install-application-initialization-in-azure-web-role-hosting-multiple-web-sites

Answer (score -1):

Since the only purpose of a VM hosting a Web Role on Windows Azure is to answer web requests, I would suppose such to sort of tuning to be the responsibility of the Cloud OS, not the Cloud App. That being said, it might interesting to check whether the Azure Cloud OS is indeed making such a tuning available by default.