# How to determine why my asp.net webforms app on azure takes so long to start up?

Tags: asp.net, performance, azure, webforms, azure-web-roles

I have an ASP.NET (webforms) app hosted on windows azure, on an XS sized instance. All is working well except that when I navigate to the site for the first time after not using it for a while it's *really* slow - like over 45 seconds!! Once it's up and running the pages are nice and fast; it's just the initial load that takes ages.

**How can I diagnose where this time is being spent?** I already have logging (to the database) within SessionStart event and two requests in different browsers started 10 seconds apart both get logged in the same second, suggesting any logging or other code I add isn't executed until after all the time is spent. Or possibly the database connection is taking a really long time.

I realise there are a few things that are likely to be affecting this, e.g.

- It's on an XS instance. They're not big.
- My code is currently built in Debug mode. That makes for bigger assemblies and pdb files that need to be loaded, so it's slower than it could be.
- Sites just take a little while to load. That's why people [change the idleTimeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479241/does-windows-azure-support-the-application-warm-up-module-or-something-similar/7866140) and possibly the recycling interval.
- I'm using Telerik controls which are pretty big, weighing in with 32mb of dlls. (But none used on the first page).

But I'd like an approach I can use to identify what is taking all the time, e.g. get some measurements on what's happening and how long it's taking, or simply more things I can do to try to make it start up faster.

On my development machine with local database & web the startup time is maybe 5 seconds. *Possibly* it's just 10x faster than an XS instance, but if that's the case how can I work out what's taking the time on my local machine so I can try to improve it?

Answer (score 2):

Well your XS instance doesn't have a dedicated CPU and a low I/O performance. And like you already noticed, this could have an impact on how fast your application pool starts. The fact that you're loading the Telerik assemblies (32mb) will have some impact and that's not something you can easily change.

What you can do to improve the startup time is the following:

1. Use the Release build configuration. This means you'll have optimized assemblies that are smaller and might contain less code (depending on preprocessor directives).
2. Use the [application initialization module](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/iis-8-0-application-initialization-module-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/) which comes included in IIS8 (you'll need to change the osFamily to 3). IIS will make sure the application is started right away and will simulate requests to your application in order to start it directly. Most of the time this means your users won't be affected by the initial load. In case they do hit the site while it's starting, application initialization module allows you to show a loading page while it's starting the application pool.