# install Application Initialization in Azure Web Role hosting multiple web sites

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-deployment, azure-cloud-services

i have azure role hosted as cloud service, i am trying to install the application initialization as suggested in below link:

http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/iis-8-0-application-initialization-module-in-a-windows-azure-web-role

but how will all my sites in this single WebRole will remain warmed up?

I have followed up the steps told in above link. But not sure how it will managed with multiple websites in single role.