# I have compiled project code and views, still getting long wait after app pool refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

Now this this could be a simple question, but I am a little confused.

I published my MVC3 C# .NET web application to a IIS folder. I have selected the precompile options and unchecked the "allow site to be updateable" to ensure Views are compiled, and they are, to ".compiled" files in bin ie:

```
_createoredit.cshtml.1c32bb75.compiled
```

The "cs" files are compiled into the main project dll ie.

```
myApp.dll
```

On first call, the page can take 30 - 60 secs to load then < 1 sec

If I refresh the app pool the page then takes 30-60 secs again.

My current understanding is that this time delay is caused by the jitter compiling the byte code in the dll into binary code ??

I had hoped to significantly increase response time post app pool refresh by precompiling the Views. However not so, but perhaps this is due to the fact the my project file is in byte code, and that I need to do something more to it?

I do understand that you can keep web apps warm by repinging the site, but the reality is that app pools do get refreshed for strange reasons. Also I am using Azure. So I would really like to use deployed units of code that will run as quickly as possible after a refresh.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

Having precompiled the Views and deployed to Azure Websites using Shared or Standard instances, I still get the initial load lag, instigated by an AppPool refresh which I deliberately cause by a resave of the Web.config. To be honest I am not seeing any significant benefit in precompiling the Views, as I still get a time penalty when .NET seems to further compile the ".compiled" views on first load.

**EDIT2**

More information in reference to @Yishal's post.

I am using Basic on dev and standard on test. I have enabled "Always on" which is in effect an autoping. I also have "Uptime-robot" autopinging. I have also tested a seperate shared site with all Views precompiled. The autopinging helps to keep the app pool warm. However if the app pool refreshes ie via web.config resave (for testing) then one get the long initial wait again. Can be up to a minute, then < 1 sec for same page. The only thought I have is that it is taking ~ 60 secs for the project.dll(.net p-code) to be compiled down to binary and be held in RAM.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I share your questions (frustrations?) I've all but given up on this, after reading every single piece of information on the topic. An ASP.NET MVC application always seems to take at least a few seconds (5+) up to about 30 seconds to get going after recompiling. Nothing I've ever tried has changed this. Pinging the website every minute or so is the only solution I've seen that has come close. +1 hope you get an answer.

Comment: @RowanFreeman, Perhaps it was not such a silly question after all. Thank you for your reply. If I get an answer I will post. Seems so clunky that one has to keep app pool alive to avoid this issue. MS now has an "Always on" feature on Azure Standard Websites, but it is an auto ping under the bonnet, rather than a "do not recyle" setting for the app pool.

Comment: This may be slightly off topic, but would be interesting, but is there any improvement with MVC4 or MVC5 over MVC3 on this issue? It is more of interest, since I am not in a position to upgrade my app to 4 or 5 over night.

Comment: I don't think there's any major performance improvements in this regard with MVC 4 or 5.

Comment: hmmmm.... Ok, good to know and thanks.... Just done some testing on Azure Standard Websites FYI. Not good.

Comment: We do have some performance to gain with MVC5, not in start up though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Web sites free tier, this is expected. If you are not please let me know, and we can look more into it.

Also note that pre-compiling view does not assist in start-up time at all for your scenario, particularly if you try to his a single page. This single page will get compiled on the fly and the cost for that is rather small.

Comment: Hi @Yishal, Thanks for the post. See EDIT2 for my comment. Would love to hear your thoughts. It is this initial warm up period that is so problematic. There are a few IIS tweaks/features to help, but not on Azure Websites since it is locked down in respect of these.

Comment: What is the warmup time you see on your own IIS machine? I'm assuming you are using ASPX pages?

Comment: I think my main issue now is to do with initialisation of my EF entities which are reasonably complicated. For the moment I have a startup process which warms it up and I have autoping running.

Comment: consider running warmup code as a background task (if possible at all), of course you have to be super careful about thread safety.

It will mean your first requests might go slower until warm up has completed but your site startup time will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

When you pre-compile an application and then deploy it on the server application pool will be restarted and take a little bit to reload itself.After that with new featur in aspnet it still sleeping untile next request which will be show in few millisecond.It is a new feature of iis 8.

however if you're not on iis 8 when application pool has been restarted take some time to complete all the hosting process and to unload, re-load and recompile the site in order to serve it in next request.It is normal behavior.You can do it thosand times and it will always the same :)

Hope it help

Comment: Thanks for this. Locally I am using IIS7.5 on Win7. My deployment platform is Azure which I assume to be the latest and greatest ie IIS8+. I am currently deploying to Azure, so perhaps it will run more quickly. What is this "new featur in aspnet" called?

Comment: let me check the article but is not in aspnet i'm sorry in IIS let me take the link i will update soon

Comment: here you may find some stuff about dynamic activation and more :) http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/dynamic-site-activation-in-iis85

Comment: Thanks for this. I have just been doing more testing in Azure and although the Views are "precompiled" as ".compiled" files, I still get a big hit when I resave the web.config which forces an AppPool recycle. I am using quite a lot of Views to render XHtml for a document. So initial load may take tween 60 and 90 secs to generate document and then about 4 secs thereafter. So it is weird that these are Views are compiled, yet they still take a long time to respond on initial load.

Comment: when webconfig has been changed application pool restart ....always but if you change only files and dll will be recompiled only this in order to return newest version.Personal suggestion: if your web config is not changed ....DON'T RE-UPLOAD IT :D

Comment: I was changing the Web.Config to deliberately force a refresh for testing purposes. When you say "ut if you change only files", what type of files are your talking about, non precompiled viewss. CS files will need to be recompiled into MyApp.dll anyway.

Comment: Checking your bin folder after that application has been rebuilt you will find .dll extension and so on. you can reupload all except your webconfig :D lol

Comment: I use this way more more more time when i need to make several changes in few hours :D

Comment: Precompiling the views will not make a huge difference in serving the first page, all you are really save is the time to compile a single page which is rather small. And not close to 60 seconds.

Comment: So what will make a difference in "serving that first page". By your comment I am assuming that the main issue is fully compiling "MyApp.dll" ie the main project dll?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at this post on IIS 8's Application Initialization Module on Azure: http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/iis-8-0-application-initialization-module-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/ (originally linked from: [Does Windows Azure support the Application Warm-Up module or something similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479241/does-windows-azure-support-the-application-warm-up-module-or-something-similar)).

Comment: Thank you for this. However initially my interest is in sorting this issue for Azure Websites not Webroles. That will come later.